# Is the hybrid solution the best one for developing a web app?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, architecture

I need to build a web app that has to be "universal". By universal I mean that I need it to be available online and offline, and usable on mobile platform and pc's and mac.

I need to store and retrieve the info and I want the app to be updated when its online.

Since I need to port the info to a SQL database I thought about building an CMS that would build the app for each client using the SQL database. That app would run with a Nosql Db in the background that would return the data to the master (couchdb) and then I would take that info and parse it to store it in the SQL Database ...

I thought using the couchdb engine would be the best solution because I need the data to be available online and offline.

The question now ...

- First is it a good idea?
- Any other suggestions I could build on?(can be anything)
- Is the hybrid solution a good idea?
- What offline storage easily replicable I could use for a web app (
  easy to install at the client facilities?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target HTML5 browsers and use [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to store the data for offline use. These articles give pointers on how to synchronise the local and central storage.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744522/best-way-to-synchronize-local-html5-db-websql-storage-sqlite-with-a-server-2
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106961/html5-local-datastore-and-sync-across-devices

Comment: its a good solution but i need it to be linked to the master db at my work.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: put things in perspective really useful edit ... that s a wrap ... im gonna use nosql... now the question is couch or mongo ...lol